# how to pass jsonarray to adapter in android

Tags: android, json

Hi in the below code how to pass array to the adapter. after passing values is an json array it was showing error values.

can any one help me

**json resp**

```
{
  "RESULT": "SUCCESS",
  "PLACE": [
    "Bangalore",
    "Kochi"
  ]
}

URL = "";

        Map<String, String> valuesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        String json1 = gson.toJson(valuesMap);
        Log.d("Gson Json", json1);

        // result is the response result that we get from server for List of Brand
        result = UrlRequester.post(getActivity(), URL, json1);
        Log.d("res", result);

        // JSON parsing for the request we got for Brand
        try {
            jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {

            values = jsonObj.getJSONArray("PLACE");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        final ArrayAdapter adapterSearch = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        mACtxt_City.setAdapter(adapterSearch);
```

Comment: "showing error values"... *sigh*

Comment: values this one is asking for list

Comment: What are error values?

Comment: cast 3rd parameter to java.lang.list

Answer (score 0):

Replace following code:

```
// JSON parsing for the request we got for Brand
        try {
            jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {

            values = jsonObj.getJSONArray("PLACE");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        final ArrayAdapter adapterSearch = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
```

With this one:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
            values = jsonObj.getJSONArray("PLACE");

            for(int i= 0; i<values.length(); i++)
            {
                list.add(values.getString(i));
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        final ArrayAdapter adapterSearch = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
```

Just parsed the array and stored in list and pass to constructor
I did not run this because of time.
Hope this will help.
Thanks